# How can I read a cookie I programmatically set?

Tags: 9, cookies

I can programmatically set a cookie in a Drupal 9 controller and I can see that cookie in Chrome's developer tools. However, I *cannot* programmatically get that cookie from a hook.

I'm using the *SAML Service Provider* module. I'm extending the `SamlSPDrupalLoginController::initiate()` function with this code to set a cookie.

```php
setcookie('stv_saml_idp_id', $idp->get('id'), time() + 86400, '/');
```

That seems to work fine as I can see the cookie in the Chrome developer tools. Unfortunately, when I attempt to get the cookie back with the following code, I get no results.

```php
function mymodule_saml_sp_drupal_login_user_attributes_alter($user, array $attributes) {
  // …
  $cookies = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->cookies;
  $idp_id = $cookies->get('stv_saml_idp_id');
  //…
}
```

*However*, if (as a test) I embed the same code in a Basic page, I *can* get the cookie.

I have also tried  with `$idp_id = $_COOKIE['stv_saml_idp_id'];` but
I still could not get the cookie.

How can I read a cookie I programmatically set?

Comment: What are the cookie attributes in fact in the browser?

Comment: Related: is the browser sending that cookie in subsequent requests?

Answer (score 4):

Oh... thanks **cilefen**. That was a good question that helped me find the problem :-)

I was writing down the attributes to post in reply when I realised my cookie domain differed from the Drupal session cookie domain by 1 character. *My* cookie domain was:

```
mysub.domain.com
```

Whereas, the session cookie had leading dot like so:

```
.mysub.domain.com
```

So, the solution was to explicitly set the cookie Domain exactly the same as the Drupal session Domain:

```
setcookie('stv_saml_idp_id', $idp->get('id'), time() + 86400, '/', '.mysub.domain.com');
```

Thanks again.